# How to change images in CSS keyframes animation?

Tags: image, css

Just trying to do a simple image transition **from one image to the next** for up to as many images as needed. Tried using this banner tutorial but that didn't load the image up

```
background:url(/images/newnew.jpg) repeat-x;
```

So if  you know how to simply change the image at a set time interval I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: As Dai said, background-image can not be animated. What could work though, is laying different images (or elements with background images) on top of each other, and manipulate their opacity.

Comment: You can't animate `background-image` but can `background-position` http://dev.bradsknutson.com/demos/css-background-animation/

Comment: How about you think about it this way. Images with the same translateY property but different opacity, such that when one image disapears, the other image appears

Answer (score 0):

According to this article from Mozilla's website ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties ), the `background-image` property is not animatable.

If you want to change the `background-image` of a box over time you'll need to use a script.

...and if you're living in the late-1990s, you could also call-upon `HTML+TIME` (but we don't talk about that anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not part of the webkit spec, changing the background is possibly on some browsers (but not all, so this method isn't the recommended route). It is advisable for a backwards compatable site to have the  image in an unclickable div with width & height 100% for both the image, rather than as a background for the whole div.

It is possible to work this with hover, as shown on [this page](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg6).

```
#background {
margin:0 auto;
transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
background-image:url("/images/bg.jpg");}
```

Combining this with one of the keyframe transition tutorials should allow you to transition a background.